# Find the required probability.

Tags: probability

Two balls are drawn from an urn containing $m$ balls numbered from $1$ to $m$ . The first ball is kept if it is numbered 1 and returned to the urn otherwise. What is the probability that the second ball drawn is numbered 2?

Comment: First I have tried to find the probability of getting no. 1 ball and it's compliment.

Comment: What is this probability?

Comment: Well I guess I have found the answer.

Comment: Yes... I was trying to help (without giving the full answer)!

Comment: Thank you it really help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add up the two cases. The first gives $\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{m-1}$, since the first ball is kept. The second gives $\frac{m-1}{m}\frac{1}{m}$. Hence the probability is

$$ P = \frac1m\left(\frac{1}{m-1}+\frac{m-1}{m}\right) = \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m^2(m-1)}. $$

Comment: Yeah I got the same. Thanks!!